# A user can't add a comment on the answers of him own bounty, because it requires rep

Tags: support, reputation, comments, bounty, privileges

I'm a frequent user on Stack Overflow** site, and very sporadic on Super User site.

I've reached the +50 rep on  Super User site, then I did a bounty because I need to solve a problem.

#### Problem

After publishing the bounty, I received answers, but I can't just add a comment on the answers that I've received on my own bounty because this action requires +50 rep!!

So, this is a not ending loop, I consider this a bad design issue decision from developers, who lets add comments on my own question, but not on the answers of my own bounty?, how is possible it works like that?.

I feel quite angry and also impotent, because I've published "questions" on Super User praying for just 20 points (2 or 3 upvotes!) to reach the +50 rep to add a comment on my own bounty, but instead that I've received all downvotes, like this: https://superuser.com/questions/854532/stackexchange-design-issue?

To think:

I've helped many people on Stack Overflow because is an area that I can manage to help, but I can't do the same on Super User, which is an area about hardware and software (windows in general), so I can't just go and try to gain some votes helping people, because I'm unable to help.

The most important thing is, if an user reached the 50 points to make a bounty, the same user should have privileges to add a comment on the answers that he receives, if not then why I did a bounty?, that does not helps anybody, I need to add a comment on an answer that I've received to clear unclear things.

Its horrible that I should be wasting time talking again and again about the same problem, in superuser, and here.

A revision of "Add comments" privilege is needed, but that maybe will be discarded or maybe not but a revision will take so long and my bounty ends shortly.

So please, y pray again the moderators to give me the privilege to add a comment on my own bounty answers, I have 31 rep (by the moment) on Super User, and I need +50 to perform that action.

Comment: People are not going to reward you reputation for asking a question that isn't on topic.  The fact you don't understand this is concerning.  The fact you asked a question and it was deleted for not being on topic then you reposted it indicates you don't understand how the Stackexchange community works.  You will get no love from me for begging for reputation instead of simply earning it.

Comment: I understand how it works, I re-asked because I feel indignated because i should not be suffering this design issue and to catch moderator attention because otherwise I don't know how to solve this issue (I mean an email, or something else). I would like to but I can't earn rep in SuperUser. you are not comprehensive with this kind of problem. but thanks for your oppinion!

Comment: And please, stop downvoting me for nothing! or maybe I could not add a comment here to share my oppinion with you... (sarcasm, because here I can add a comment, but in my own bounty I can't)

Comment: There are tons of ways you could earn reputation.  You could go through all questionable questions that exists and earn up to 1000 reputation points by proposing an edit and getting it accepted.  I will downvote questions I don't agree with on meta websites.  I will downvote questions that are not on topic, low quality, and question I believe are not helpful.

Comment: I didn't knew that, the thing that I can't do is help users because SuperUser is not my area. I will try what you have suggested me, but anyways the problem still exist

Comment: You can research the problems like anyone else.  You can post answers to those questions you researched.  You can answer your own existing questions that have been answered by somebody else.  There is lots you can do to earn reputation.

Comment: downvotes on meta == I disagree

Comment: I'm totally sure that the people who "disagree" downvoting has +1k rep at least (like you) and this problem does not affect them, they don't get inside the skin and the point of view of the user who creates a bounty and after that RIDICULOUSLY does not have permission to add a comment on him own bounty. come on, still anybody talked ANYTHING about the problem exposed here, the real problem is not a lack of rep or a massive downvoters, its a design issue. thanks anyways.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - You are right.  I don't understand why you cannot just simply earn the reputation like everyone else but want to be just given it.

Comment: Give rep or give the NECESSARY privilege to perform a basic action, action that can be performed on my own question but not on the answers that I receive on my own bounty... one of those two things should be ok, because when a person commits an error (in this case the developers who designed the "Commentary" privilege) at least they (StackExchange Staff) should have the consideration to solve the issue to the affected user (me), and in this case the solution is giving rep, or giving the privilege FOR BOUNTIES (for me and everyone affected), easy as that.

Comment: Instead of that, I'm only getting bad opinions, but hey, I respect all kind of opinions ...but at certain point everyone trheated me like a delincuent, a homeless, or a retarded, even a moderator thinked about a suspension of my account (in the answer below) only to expose a bug issue in the wrong site, well, then what more I can say?. Thanks StackExchange, thanks for this friendly treatment for one of your frequently users. that is, one guy tries to report a problem to solve/find a friendly solution, and the user finishes getting this sh*t.

Comment: Oh, and about what you've suggested me to earn points suggesting edits, I don't have the necessary rep to suggest an edit. so see, see if you really will see that there is a real problem.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - You can propose edits to existing question and answers and other people will approve them.  Here is a list of the [privileges](http://superuser.com/help/privileges)

Comment: You can solve your immediate problem without additional rep in two ways.  1) Modify your question to incorporate additional discussion to address issues with answers instead of commenting on the answers.  2)You can comment on your own posts, so add a comment on your question and begin it with @username.  The user will receive a notice in his site mailbox at the top of the page.

Comment: Perhaps if you had just said "Hey, I think it'd be a good idea to allow people who've placed a bounty on someone else's question to comment on new answers regardless of their rep., similar to as if the question was their own" instead of getting "angry", complaining about how you time is so wasted, and insulting the developers, you'd have gotten a better response. Anyhow, seems like a reasonable request, bad way to put it. +/-0 ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 My English is not so good to express myself as I really would like to do in some circunstances, avoiding angry writting in this case, anyways I talk all with respect, angry with the problem itself, but respecting everyone (devs included). thanks for comment, everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mods *cannot* explicitly enable privileges like that - You'll need to re-earn them like anyone else by posting *quality* answers. This is by design - its the *opportunity cost* of putting out a bounty, and something I urge folk to consider *before* posting a bounty.

I'd also add that *begging* people to upvote you, through the misuse of questions and answers is bad form.

I'd add that the two questions you posted would be considered abusive, and I was inclined to stick you with a suspension for doing so. Reputation reflects trust and understanding of the system, and I see a display of neither.

As for downvotes - On the main site, they were completely deserved. I have no clue why you would consider things would have happened otherwise especially after I *commented* about it with your first question.

Here on meta, downvotes are a sign people *disagree* with you.

Comment: We have talked in private and you only needed 1 time to advertise me about what I've did, then I have understood what I've did and I 've said you that you don't need to worry because I don't pretend to re-ask this issue in SuperUser because I've received info about where I should ask this (in meta) then was only a lack of information to do things right. If after that you really think that I deserve a suspension of my account then just this is incredible, what more I should expect from moderators?. Seems like everybody preffers to ignore the real problem and sanctionate an user who is in help.

Comment: An user can add a comment on him own question. an user with 50 rep can realize a bounty, the same user can't add a comment on the answers that receive on him own bounty because... ridiculously it needs rep to comment them?. Why anybody talks about that? stop fixing at what I've did, and please, talk about the problem and try to find a solution about me, is not only me, is the same things for all "new" users. thanks.

Comment: What you did *is* a problem though. You're like "I can't be bothered to take the effort to research a single question to get the rep I need to comment", but rather spam the site, beg for rep *and* demand everything change cause you didn't check if you had enough rep before hand.

Comment: OK, I appreciate your words, but I see nothing to do, as I expected the real problem is totally ignored here, as I expected when I've commented you that in private before your posted answer here. I understand that you've nothing to do with the privileges, but you didn't talked about the problem and only about the subjective problem (which in your opinnion is myself). This is what an user deserves? everyone included you and me is wasting time because a design issue of commentary privileges. that's the objective problem.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - If you had no created the same question after it was deleted then Journeyman wouldn't have had voice his opinion.